# Losing hyperlink between ArcMap and Google Earth

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth, hyperlink

Most of my colleagues use Google Earth to check our infrastructure. A few years before I started here, the hyperlinks from our GIS to Google Earth lost connection. The path is still in the "plan_path", but now the users on Google Earth have to copy/paste the link to the file explorer. My predecessor couldn't figure out, and I can't either, so I decided to ask here. I attached a couple screenshots.

[image: This is our ArcMap with hyperlink shown.]

[image: This is the Google Earth equivalent. The link is shown, but does not work.]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking? Are you saying you have created a KML file which you give to your colleagues and now when they click on it in Google Earth it does not open the pdf file?

Comment: Correct. I use ArcMap to edit our GIS information. When changes are made, I export the layers to the district KML that our staff uses. Apparently a few years ago, the hyperlinks worked for Google Earth, and now they do not. I have a feeling the spaces between words could be a part of the issue.

Comment: Before you invest too much effort in renaming everything, create a simple KML with a point and a path then explore if it the spaces. Alternatively may be Google have changed something and your output is fine? Also try using ArcGIS Earth as an alternative to Google Earth?

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. We have a lot of people in our district that need access to the information, so we use Google Earth on their computers since it is free. Only several of us in engineering have ESRI licenses.

Comment: ArcGIS Earth is free...

Comment: Thank you. I've used ArcScene, ArcGIS Pro, ArcMap, ArcGIS Online, and Collector. I have no idea how I have not heard of this. I'm going to download it, test it out, and hopefully distribute it to the company. I appreciate your help.